# Using COUNT in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a following dql in my repostory class:

```
public function find2($id)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b', 'branch', 'pai', 'dri', 'COUNT(dri) AS ct')
        ->leftJoin('b.branches', 'branch')
        ->leftJoin('branch.productAllocationItems','pai')
        ->leftJoin('pai.DRItems', 'dri')
        ->where('b.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->andWhere('ct > 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(); 
}
```

My problem is COUNT doesnt seem to work, is there any wrong in my query?
I just want to return entity whose DRItems based on the condition. Thanks.

I got the following error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr0' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> ->having('ct > 1')

instead of

> ->andWhere('ct > 1')

```
public function find2($id)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b', 'branch', 'pai', 'dri', 'COUNT(dri) AS ct')
        ->leftJoin('b.branches', 'branch')
        ->leftJoin('branch.productAllocationItems','pai')
        ->leftJoin('pai.DRItems', 'dri')
        ->where('b.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->having('ct > 1')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get count by change `select` statement.

As per [**documentation**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) select can be use below format

but for count you can achieve with comma separated fields with count , just like we do it in **SQL**.

```
// Example - $qb->select('u')
// Example - $qb->select(array('u', 'p'))
// Example - $qb->select($qb->expr()->select('u', 'p'))
public function select($select = null);
```

**Change**

```
->select('b', 'branch', 'pai', 'dri', 'COUNT(dri) AS ct')
```

**To**

```
->select( 'b,branch, pai, dri ,COUNT(dri) AS ct')
```